# vb script to remove only specific lines in a text file

Tags: vbscript

Would someone be kind enough to help me out with a vbscript?  I have a simple text file stored on `D:\Projects`.

Here's a small sample of the contents (done in Notepad):

```
Header 1 (this will always vary and be one simple line of text)

Captain:  John Doe 1
Team Roster: Temp\filename blah blah
Team Roster: Permanent\filename blah blah

Header 2 (this will always vary and be one simple line of text)

Captain:  John Doe 2
Team Roster: Temp\filename blah blah
Team Roster: Permanent\filename blah blah
```

What I need is for everything to be deleted in the file except for the header and each of the  headers needs to be repeated.  So the end result looks like this:

```
Header line 1
Header line 1
Header line 2
Header line 2  etc...
```

I realize people come here in their free time to volunteer so any help would be very much appreciated.  I don't know how to program otherwise I would do this myself.  Thanks.

Comment: Header 1, Header 2 -- do you have an example of a header?  Or, does the Header change each line, but Captain and Team Roster are always the same?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Captain" and "Team Roster" are always excepted to exist in the file and the Header is changing, you could do something like this (output will be .stripped.txt)

```
stripFile "D:\Projects\File.txt"

Sub stripFile(fileName)

  Dim strOutputFile, strInputFile, strLine
  Dim objFSO, objOutputFile, objInputFile

  strOutputFile = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName)) & fileName & ".stripped.txt"

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

  Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutputFile, 8, True)   
  Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileName, 1)

  Do While objInputFile.AtEndOfStream = False
    strLine = objInputFile.ReadLine

    If Mid(strLine, 1, 7) <> "Captain" Then
      If Mid(strLine, 1, 11) <> "Team Roster" Then
        If strLine <> "" Then
          objOutputFile.WriteLine strLine
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Loop  

  objOutputFile.Close
  objInputFile.Close

  Set objOutputFile = Nothing
  Set objInputFile = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks QuickNull. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error message when I run your code:
line 12
char 3
Error: Bad file name or number
code 800A0034

It says bad filename or number.
code 800A0034

Comment: I would need more information than that.  If you copy/paste your example into a file, and run this snippet against the file, the output will be:

Header 1 (this will always vary and be one simple line of text) and 

Header 1 (this will always vary and be one simple line of text)

Comment: When runtime error says error at line such & such... is it counting the blank lines in the code?  I'm trying to figure out where this is failing....

Comment: Well, right. If the line starts with Captain, Team Roster or is empty, nothing is written to the output file. Anything else will be.  I just tested it again, I copy/pasted your example to a test file, ran that script code passing the file with your example.  It creates a new file with the two Header lines. The file must contain something else.

Comment: Thats weird. it's not working for me for some reason.  I thought there must be something in my original file so I created a new text file by copying & pasting what I have in my OP.  Still getting the runtime error message as noted previously.

Comment: Without you giving me the specific error code(s) and message, I'm not quite sure how to help.