# Use vbscript to delete first line only of text file

Tags: vbscript

I want to delete the first line of a text file with VBScript.

I have tried this:

```
Const FOR_READING = 1
Const FOR_WRITING = 2
strFileName = "le_file.txt"
iNumberOfLinesToDelete = 1

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING)
strContents = objTS.ReadAll
objTS.Close

arrLines = Split(strContents, vbNewLine)
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING)

For i=0 To UBound(arrLines)
    If i > (iNumberOfLinesToDelete - 1) Then
        objTS.WriteLine arrLines(i)
    End If
Next
```

Even though I have `iNumberOfLinesToDelete` set to 1, what happens is that every line gets deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove-a-specific-line-of-a-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683456/vb-script-to-remove-only-specific-lines-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code before posting? What do you think happens with `Split()` if it can't find the character you wish to spilt on? I'll tell you, it returns the whole string as the only element in the array. Chances are it can't find `vbCrLf` in the string returned, maybe the file uses linefeeds instead *(`vbLf`)*? Only way to know is debug the code, check how many times the loop is triggered via a counter for example.

Answer (score 0):

(Late reply)
Simpler - and more robust solution:

```
Const FOR_READING = 1
Const FOR_WRITING = 2

strFileName = "le_file.txt"

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING)
objTS.ReadLine ' Read the first line
strContents = ""
if not f.AtEndofStream then strContents = objTS.ReadAll ' Read and save the rest (if there is any more)
objTS.Close

Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING)
f.write Contents ' Write it back
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub deleteline()

  Const FOR_READING = 1

  Const FOR_WRITING = 2

  strFileName = "textfile.txt"

  Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING)

  If objTs.AtEndOfStream Then window.close:Exit sub

  objTS.ReadLine ' Read the first line

  strContents = ""

  if not objts.AtEndofStream then strContents = objTS.ReadAll

  objTS.Close

  Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING)

  objTs.write strContents ' Write it back

  window.close

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).